# What is the cause of these black spots on my chair?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Before voting to close this question please read the note section.

I saw something really weird a week ago on my plastic armchair. There were a large number of black spots on my chair and I don't know how did it happen.

[image]

---

I tried to think for the reason and my intuitions are that since the chair is more often  kept out in sunlight , so may be the electrons from the atoms on upper surface went through photoelectric (not surely) and thermionic emissions and because of this there are no more electrons to re-emit the photons coming on it and hence it is appearing black in colour.

---

However as I said , those were my intuitions and I am just a high schooler , so it is quite possible to have wrong intuitions.

So I want to know the actual reason behind this effect.

One more thing which I would like to add is that when I scratch those spot with my nails :) and they were not slippery , I get a complete white apperance (visible in the picture too).

So it would be helpful if someone gives me the reason for both the blackish as well as the whitish appearance.

**NOTE** : Those black spots are not black moulds for sure (see the picture below)  since I touched those regions with my bare hands and there was nothing like wet and slippery . So I think it needs physics and not biology for reasoning this effect. Also I should mention that it's an old chair and was bought five to six years ago.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @John Rennie why do you think so ? I have checked it , it's not a black mould and there must some physics for the colour change.

Comment: Re, "when I scratch those spot with my nails, I get a complete white apperance." _Powdery_ white? I bet that the surface of the plastic has been broken down by exposure to sunlight. I'm not qualified to talk about how that might impact the ability of black mold to grow on the surface, but I suspect that it might be a factor.

Comment: Re, "why...non-physical?" Physics underlies _every_ question, of course, but some things (e.g., chemistry) are better understood at a higher level, and some things (e.g., biology, animal behavior, the weather, ...) are better understood at ever higher and higher levels.

Comment: @Solomon Slow  its not a black mold and I have checked for it. It must be something what you and my intuitions say.

Comment: I think it is a kind of fungus called "mildew", see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildew

Comment: @Quillo I have mentioned clearly that there is nothing biological here why don't anyone understand this ?!! There is nothing like mould or mildew .

Comment: It does not look "bio" because it dried out. When this stuff attacks plastic and then someone removes it with chemical products, a black spot remains.

Comment: @Quillo what !! No one in my house did so .

Comment: Probably it's just dry because of sun and wind. If then you also scratched it, then the black spot remains cause the roots of the fungus penetrate into the plastic. Black mold attaches to the affected materials with microscopic (black) filaments that penetrate beneath the surface and it's extremely difficult to remove it.

Comment: By scratching enough, if the plastic is quite old, you just remove the layer of plastic with the roots and the spots disappear (plastic tend to acquire a sort of "sandy" or "dust" surface that you can scratch off when it's old and consumed by sunlight). Note: see also the answer about the "powdery white" of @SolomonSlow .

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly black mold/mildew. It usually appears where humidity is higher than normal.

Comment: no I don't think so. If it would have been a black mould , I need not to scratch it with nails to remove it. i could have remove it with rubbing cloths on it. Also as I said it is most of times left in open sunlight which would have killed those moulds.

Comment: a fungus? https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/19306

Comment: this mildew mold has colonized pores in the plastic surface which were created when the chair was made and which exposure to sun and air have enlarged. for this reason they cannot be scratched off. the powdery white residue is oxidized plastic, which is soft and crumbly.